# Android Build with command-line tools

Tags: android, android-build, aapt, aapt2, android-d8

I try to understand how a `.apk` file is built from source code. I know that with Android Studio or with the command `gradlew` the build can be done easily. The Android Sdk provides multiple tools that are used to build a .apk, which most of them I know what they do:

`d8`: java byte code to dalvik bytecode

`aapt2`: Compile resources and link them. This tool creates a `.apk` file of compiled resources. (It also creates `R.java` to reference the resources in the code.)

`apksigner`: Takes the `.apk` and signs it. Otherwise, it cannot be installed on an Android device.

`zipalign`: aligns uncompressed data of the `.apk`

The last two tools are used on the `apk`, which already contains all files. What I do not understand is how compiled code and compiled resources are combined? Before `aapt2` was a thing the packaging was done with `aapt`, but it is not even listed on [Androids Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line). However, `aapt` is still in the Android Sdk build-tools. The new `aapt2` has no option for packaging.

So, the question is which command-line tools and in which order are used to create a complete `.apk` from source code? Thank you!

**EDIT:** What I am looking for would be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59533703/7947994), where a `.apk` is created with the command-line step by step. Only the answer uses the old `aapt`, which I think is not used anymore.

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks to [Allen Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8385758/allen-shaw) for giving me the missing information. I was now able to compile an app with `aapt2`. The answer to my question was simply to zip the `aapt2` output and the `classes.dex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use `aapt2` command

```
aapt2 link -o output.apk
```

reference the google document [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#link)

Add .dex file into apk:

```
zip -ur app-debug.apk classes.dex
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! From the document, I read that `aapt2` only makes a `.apk` with the resource files and not including `.dex` files. The question is how I can create a `.apk` with both dex and resources?

Comment: As apk file is simply a zip file, you can use `zip -ur out.apk classes.dex` to add dex file into apk.